# Fetch API cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: node.js

I got

- a rest api deployed on heroku
- a react app deployed on heroku

the react app tries to get data from the rest api using whatwg-fetch.

```
var header = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", 'Origin': 'https://foo.bar', 'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-Requested-With'};
var options = {method: 'GET', credentials: 'include', headers: header};
fetch('https://myrest.api/foo', options)...
```

But I can't get any data, it say's

```
Fetch API cannot load https://foo.bar. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://foo.bar' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

When I try to get the data with curl it works

```
curl -H "Origin: https://foo.bar" \
     -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
     -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
     -X GET --verbose https://myrest.api/foo -D header.txt
```

and the response header (from the curl command)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.bar
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 23:52:57 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Cors is enabled in the spring boot application via @CrossOrigin

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Comment: Your error means that the browser is finding that your request and the origin of the server do not meet the proper conditions for a cross origin request.  You can't fix that from the client.  You have to fix that from the server.  To understand the problem, you need to look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger when you issue the fetch command and see EXACTLY what the browser is sending and what the server is responding with.  With that info in hand, we could tell what is missing on the server side. CURL does not have origin limitations (that's a browser thing) so that's why it works fine.

Comment: The fact that you are using credentials in your request probably means the server has to support the OPTIONS request that the browser will use to pre-flight the cross origin acceptability of this request.  You would see that clearly in the network trace I referred to above.

Comment: @jfriend00
I am now able to get the cors header via curl from the command line. I tried a request with the exact same header (see here [link](http://pastebin.com/7E8Zwr3K)) as on my react app, but in my react app I did not get the required headers ...
Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to access from one domain https://foo.bar into another domain at https://myrest.api and that is the reason for that error.

You have 2 options:

1) Merge this 2 apps into one single domain on Heruko, React and the Api apps will be under https://foo.bar domain for example and that will work for you.

2) Allow the client app domain at https://foo.bar to access into your api domain at https://myrest.api by adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header into the api app:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   next();
});
```